# recovering a windows home server (v1) hdd

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, file-permissions, data-recovery, windows-home-server

I just had my windows homeserver (v1) die

All im left with are 3 hard drives

2 of the drives show up as blank when I plug them into my usb sata reader
the 3rd drive

has 2 partitions system and Data

In Data i can see all the files i want (~70GB) but if i try to open or move the files i get an

"Error 0x80070780: the file cannot be accessed by the system" error
however I can right click and get properties (size dates etc)

Is this a permission issue or is the drive damaged?  Is there anything special i need to do to pull the data off and put it on my windows sbs server?

Comment: I'm a little curious why this got migrated to SU when it was a question about a server recovery

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out how to work around it but not the why. (if someone wants to give a technical reason I will award them the answer point)

The workaround is:

1. Plug in the other drive that appeared to have nothing on it Turn
2. Show hidden files and folders
3. The contents of the shares will be in the DE folder that is hidden normally